# Android image drawable for various resolutions

Tags: android

For using images in my android application, I will use this technique :

I put all of my images into "drawable-xhdpi" folder to let the application scale the images down for various resolutions.

I wondering does it make sense ? What is your experiences ?

Thanks for sharing...

**UPDATE:**

Maybe this method is a nice one, But an another question raises here which is :

Does this technique causes a memory leak for ldpi devices? I don't want to solve the problem by using svg images, Suppose there are bit-mapped images which are not vector based and there is no choice or alternative to replace. using a bitmap is the only choice.however using this method has a cons which will affect the overall layout and in some devices the position of relevant controls will be changed.

Answer (score 2):

While this will work, it's not ideal and not recommended. Please look at the official documentation for [Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html):

> Although the system performs scaling and resizing to make your application work on different screens, you should make the effort to optimize your application for different screen sizes and densities. In doing so, you maximize the user experience for all devices and your users believe that your application was actually designed for their devices—rather than simply stretched to fit the screen on their devices.

And:

> Provide different bitmap drawables for different screen densities
>   By default, Android scales your bitmap drawables (.png, .jpg, and .gif files) and Nine-Patch drawables (.9.png files) so that they render at the appropriate physical size on each device. For example, if your application provides bitmap drawables only for the baseline, medium screen density (mdpi), then the system scales them up when on a high-density screen, and scales them down when on a low-density screen. This scaling can cause artifacts in the bitmaps. To ensure your bitmaps look their best, you should include alternative versions at different resolutions for different screen densities.

You can use the `File / New / Image Asset` to automatically generate the scaled assets.

Comment: @David_Rawson ,I think for bitmaps which are not vector, my technique is nice , but I wondering for memory leaks issue on ldpi devices. please take a look at  the update in question body.

Comment: @S.A.Parkhid generating the scaled bitmap images won't cause a memory leak by itself. Memory leaks are caused by retaining a reference to a Bitmap in a static context etc. If you are worried about memory usage in general then, yes, the scaled bitmap images will take up less memory on those lower density devices.

Comment: @David_Rawson, Thanks for your comment , so when an app automatically resizes the bitmap (scale down) stored in hdpi folder ,does  it mean that it creates a new bitmap with really down sized image? for exmaple for a bitmap with 500x500 px , does it create(rewrite) a 250x250 bitmap in memory? or just use a physical scale transformation?

Comment: @S.A.Parkhid I think this scaling is done at runtime and in memory. That is why it is recommended that you use the asset manager to create pre-scaled images. This means there is less to do at run time hence the improvement in performance

Answer (score 1):

Best way is use `SVG` files instead of `PNG` and import them to project in Androis studio: `File -> New -> Vector Asset` or use icon fonts like https://github.com/mikepenz/Android-Iconics

SVG file is inserted to `drawable` and converted to PNG files while compile time for back compatibility, but you don't need to maintain a pack of files, but just one vector file.

Comment: Suppose , I don't want to use svg , I have a bitmap

Answer (score 0):

I use **inkscape** to create svg drawings and also to convert to png I think the conversion has better quality and supports all svg functions.

With **inkscape** and a script it is possible to do batch conversion, I have not tried it yet, until now I convert them one by one